# After downloading image from "Docker Hub", where should I put my configuration file? In data volume?

Tags: linux, docker, centos7

I am using Docker for the first time.
I downloaded a Nginx image from "Docker Hub",
I don't know where I should put my configuration file.
Put in data volume?
I read the documentation,but I am confused.

Comment: You can pass configuration through [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) or mount a host file as a [data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Dockerfile and build you own image FROM nginx base.

Then you can COPY your default.conf to /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.

Then you can build your image and run it.

Dockerfile (assumed Dockerfile and conf file are in the same folder):

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Build & run:

```
docker build -t myproxy:1.0
docker run -d -P myproxy
```

Then you can link the running container to another one, running your application.